# Body content overlapping navbar while scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am facing an error while scrolling page, body contents overlaps the navbar.

1. I have content over navbar that should disappear when scrolling, it is working fine.
2. While scrolling navbar should be fixed, this is working fine.
3. Problem is while scrolling, body contents are sliding over navbar. It should go from behind the navbar.
4. I have an image slider below navbar

Here is the code of HTML file:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow; width:200px">
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded pull-left" src="img/logo 1.png" alt="Chania" width="200" height="200">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
                <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
                <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
                <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right" style="background-color:yellow;width:200px;">
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded pull-right" src="img/logo 2.png" alt="Chania" width="200" height="200">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    menu name..
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS code of navbar:

```
.affix {
top: 0;
width: 100%; }

.affix + .container-fluid {
padding-top: 70px; }
```

CSS code for Slider

```
html, body {
height: 100%;}

.carousel, .item {
height: 70%; }

.carousel-inner {
height: 143%; }

.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover; }
```

I am beginner in bootstrap.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you create fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29975/

Answer (score 1):

You should put this in a fiddle but off the bat I would guess that your navbar should contain `position:absolute;` and `z-index:1;`

Comment: I tried absolute and relative both, in both the cases navbar disappear while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

On seeing this query i have made jsfiddle for you just check it.. You are using affix for fixing navbar.

so in css just add the followings:

```
    .affix{
width:100%;
top:0px;
}
```

And check with the z-index of your navbar keep high value for nabvar like z-index:9999;

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z3erc68p/)

All the coding looks good no issue with that. Just check my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-top:30px;` in the main Container would do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.